# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<LastLocationResModel>'

Tags: flutter, dart

here is my repository to get data from the API, and I got the error, in the bloc state management I try to use anyways but it still got the error.

I'm getting this error

type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List'

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:gms_mobile/api/api-constants.dart';
import 'package:gms_mobile/api/api-mspf.dart';
import 'package:gms_mobile/exception/page_exception.dart';
import 'package:gms_mobile/features/last_location/model/last-location-response-model.dart';

class LastLocationRepository {
  Future<List<LastLocationResModel>> doGetLastLocation() async {
    try {
      List<LastLocationResModel> LocationList = [];
      var response = await ApiMspf.getinstance
          .get(ApiServiceConstants.last_location + '/10115795/route');
      print(response);
      try {
        // LocationList = response;
        LocationList = response.map((item) {
          LocationList.add(new LastLocationResModel(
              lat: item["lat"],
              lon: item["lon"],
              timestamp: item["timestamp"]));
        }).toList();
        return LocationList;
      } catch (error) {
        throw ModelingException(message: error.toString());
      }
    } catch (error) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this

```
class LastLocationRepository {
  Future<List<LastLocationResModel>> doGetLastLocation() async {
    try {
      List<LastLocationResModel> LocationList = [];
      var response = await ApiMspf.getinstance
          .get(ApiServiceConstants.last_location + '/10115795/route');
      print(response);
      try {
          var decode = jsonDecode(response.body);
          decode.forEach((val){
             LocationList.add(LastLocationResModel(
               lat: item["lat"],
               lon: item["lon"],
               timestamp: item["timestamp"]))
          });
        return LocationList;
      } catch (error) {
        throw ModelingException(message: error.toString());
      }
    } catch (error) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}
```

Main part is below which add all data in your list and then return this list

```
 var decode = jsonDecode(response.body);
          decode.forEach((val){
            LocationList.add(LastLocationResModel(
                lat: item["lat"],
                lon: item["lon"],
                timestamp: item["timestamp"]))
          });
          return LocationList;
```

Comment: I try this solution, now it still does not work.

Comment: Here is the error message when I try you solution.

type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: also add code where you use this list

Comment: remove try catch and fetch exist line of error and tell me line number

Comment: type 'Response<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'